# Turn this simple controller code into a method

Tags: ruby-on-rails

There are a handful of words that can never show up on my webapp in any string attribute (Photo[:title], User[:name], etc). The following code works in my Controller:

```
PhotosController
  def create
    @photo = current_user.photos.build(photo_params)
    if @photo.title.include? "foo"
       @photo = nil
       flash[:warning] = "Photo failed!, restricted words"
       redirect_to new_photo_path
    else 
      if @photo.save
        flash[:success] = "Photo created!"
        redirect_to new_photo_path
      else
        flash[:warning] = "Photo failed!"
        redirect_to new_photo_path
      end  
    end  
end
```

Obviously I don't want to have to repeat myself endlessly in my controllers for each string attribute. I need to create a method that can be placed in application.rb and used across all my controllers.

Comment: First thing you could do is to make title validation in model, all the validations should always be done in model and never in controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   class Photo
     validate :title_with_foo

     def title_with_foo
       errors.add(:base, 'Photo failed!, restricted word') unless title.include? "foo"
     end
   end
```

Add a model level validation like above

Comment: thanks. i see this now in the Rails guide. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#validates-with  it looks like i can use the [:fields] example to DRY so I do not need to create these validations individually. also, your answer should be `if`, not `unless`... i am working on implementing the [:fields] example now...